# How to edit weights from keras layer with tf as theano

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

I have the following code, which uses Keras and Theano when I create layers:

```
net.add(Dense(outdim))
Wlast = net.layers[-1].W
Wlast.set_value(Wlast.get_value(borrow=True) * 0.1)
```

Are there some appropriate transformation for TF? I try this:

```
net.add(Dense(outdim))
Wlast = net.layers[-1].W
K.set_value(Wlast, K.get_value(Wlast) * 0.1)

# before it I do some import and set session: 
# from Keras import backend as K
# K.set_session(session)
```

But I'm not sure that this work in appropriate way...

Cuz I use this layer as probability output:
- in Theano version the probability vector in range [-1,-1]
- from the other side, if I use this Keras code the probability deviates greater than 1 (if I manually decrease these output weights by 0.1 - the probability distribution become closely to Theano)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I have a Theano code, which I show first and it works.
From the other hand I try to recode it to TensorFlow and the second part of code is my implementation. But it seems to me that my TF doesn't work in this place as Theano version.

Comment: @Glau what makes you think that it does not work? What's the error you get? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: You are right - the question was a bit mystery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution is to use Keras' lambdas, for example:

```
net.add(Dense(outdim))
net.add(Lambda(lambda x: x * 0.1))
```